# Proof of divergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd really appreciate some help with this question on my recent math assignment:

> Show that if $a_n > 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n = L$, where $0 < L < \infty$, then $a_n$ is divergent.

I'm really lost regarding this proof and would like an explanation if possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggestion: Try to construct an example (explicit with a sequence and $L$) to help you think about the problem.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, wouldn't we have have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 1n na_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac Ln=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$?  How could $a_n$ diverge in this case?

Comment: Do you mean that the series diverges?  Example : take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.  Then, $\lim{na_n} = \lim{n\frac{1}{n}} = 1$, but $a_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the intention here is to prove **the series** $\;\sum a_n\;$ is divergent, but this follows at once from the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), since:

$$\frac{a_n}{\frac1n}=na_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}L\;,\;\;0<L<\infty\;\;\text{, and the harmonic series}\;\sum_{n=1}\frac1n\;\;\text{diverges}$$

Comment: I think that may be it, thanks a bunch!